# Python package external dependencies

Tags: python, packaging

I'm writing a python script which uses an external library (paramiko). If I'm to release the package how do I package paramiko also? Is there anyway I can give it as we can give dependencies in java as .jar files?

Edit: What I had in my mind was giving a single script and an archive file which contains all the dependent modules, which would not require the end user to run any setup.py

Answer (score 9):

Make it a proper package and read up about setuptools: [Python setuptools link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Dependencies can be specified using 'install_requires' parameter inside the setup.py file of your package.

Comment: The above works, but if I want to give a single script and give its dependencies in an accompanying archive, the above seems overkill.

Answer (score 4):

> If I'm to release the package how do I package paramiko also?

You don't. Instead you *declare* the dependencies:

1. Install [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/) (already included with [ActivePython](http://packages.python.org/distribute/))
2. Add `install_requires` to your setup.py (eg: see [Fabric's setup.py](https://github.com/bitprophet/fabric/blob/master/setup.py#L41))

Comment: Update: Distribute has been merged back into the setuptools project, and no longer should be thought of as a separate entity. Just use setuptools.